# How do I publish FB posts on my website with the same display of the facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed

I know how to retrieve the posts data from FB.api, and already menage to parse the data and display the inner data of each posts. but i want each feed to look the same as the facebook home page feeds look like.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ takes the feed from a Page and displays it in the same format as on Facebook.
Otherwise you'll need to style it yourself manually, making sure it doesn't look confusingly similar to Facebook's own interface.

Comment: how does the like-box help?
I want to save the post data in my DB and then present it on my website by the post id. also, i'll save other users feed if they will give me the required access token

Comment: Well then see the other half of my answer; you'll have to format it manually once you retrieve it from the API

Comment: so, as far as you know, FB API doesn't support this issue? 
copying the css and html pattern is a mess!
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Open Graph. The result is a JSON data feed, which you can stream to your site as html or load is up into a webpage. I would recommend using ajax or loading it as RAW JSON using JavaScript to render it...

```
            var Appid = 12341234; // User the one FB gave you
            var AppSecret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET"; // Use the one FB gave You
            var PageIdOrName = "matt.j.crawford"; // This could be a number or an offical name


            var tokenRequest = String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", Appid, AppSecret);
            var token = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(tokenRequest).Split(new char[] { '=' })[1];
            var feedRequest = String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/feed?access_token={1}", PageIdOrName, token);
            var feed = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(feedRequest).Replace("\\/", "/");

            var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var finalObject = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(feed);
```

These wasn't any real documentation on this so... I just figured it out.

Don't load this before rendering the page as it takes a few seconds to complete the loading, one option is to use an IHttpHandler and load it as a JavaScript file and render it server side....

Another option is use ajax to load rendered html after page load.